# How can I save my prediction values as strings in my logistic regression model in python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, logistic-regression, prediction

this code give me prediction values as 1 0r 0.But I want print them as 'Success' or 'Failure'.Is there a way for that?

```
prediction = pd.DataFrame(predictions2, columns=['predictions']).to_csv('prediction.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is map 0 and 1 to Failure and Success using a dictionary

```
prediction = pd.DataFrame(predictions2, columns=['predictions'])
prediction['predictions'] = prediction['predictions'].astype(int)
prediction["predictions"] = prediction.predictions.map({0:'Failure', 1:'Success'})
prediction.to_csv('prediction.csv', index=False)
```

You have to ensure that the data type of "predictions" is int.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience with pandas, but if you just want to assign those values to those outputs, one way is with a dictionary (posted as I type). You can also use a ternary operator. Ex:

```
prediction = pd.DataFrame(predictions2, columns ['predictions']).to_csv('prediction.csv')
result = 'Success' if prediction == 1 else 'Failure'
print(result)
```

This can be further reduced to:

```
print('Success' if prediction == 1 else 'Failure')
```

Note: Use 1 if the output is an int, use '1' if string.

Answer (score 0):

Thank You All.it's solved!

```
**mydict ={0:'Failure',1:'Success'}
predictions2 = [mydict[i] for i in predictions2]
print(predictions2)
predictions2= pd.DataFrame(predictions2, columns=['predictions']).to_csv('prediction3.csv', index=False)
```